# Responsive Navigation Not Showing All Items

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Hello I am currently learning responsive design and I am trying to make a responsive navigation bar which turns in to a menu when visited on a phone or mobile device! Everything works except not all the navigation items show on the mobile device and I am not sure why! This is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul style="padding-left: 0px;">

        <li class="logo"> <a href="#">RONNIE<b>GURR</b></a></li>

                            <section class="div_navbar_items">
                              <li class="navbar_items"> <a href="#home">HOME</a> </li>
                              <li class="navbar_items"> <a href="#about_me">ABOUT US</a> </li>
                              <li class="navbar_items"> <a href="#skills">GALLERY</a> </li>
                              <li class="navbar_items"> <a href="#projects">SHOP</a> </li>
                              <li class="navbar_items"> <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a> </li>
                            </section>

                            <li class="icon">
                              <a href="#" onclick="navBarFunction()"> &#9776;</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <script src="js/responsive.js"></script>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.navbar li.logo,
.navbar li.navbar_items {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar li a {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li.navbar_items a:hover {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  /*   padding-bottom: 5px; */
}

.navbar li.icon {
  display: none;
}

.div_navbar_items {
  float: right;
  padding-right:1%;
}
/*Start of mobile nav*/
@media screen and (max-width:875px) {
  .navbar li.navbar_items {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 19px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:875px) {
  .navbar.responsive {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(236,201,205, 1);
    transition: background-color .6s;
  }

  .navbar.responsive li.logo {
    floatL: left;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .div_navbar_items {
    float: none;
    padding-right:0;
  }

  .navbar.responsive li.navbar_items {
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .navbar.responsive li.navbar_items a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar.responsive li.navbar_items a:hover{
    color:#17171e;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;

  }
}
/*End of mobile nav*/
```

And here is the JS:

```
function navBarFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyEoWY

Comment: Your code is kind of hard to work with, any chance you can recreate a working version in codepen or jsfiddle? Seems like an easy issue to fix.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich yeah no problem

Comment: @DanielZuzevich https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyEoWY

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you in the right direction, then you can decide upon what you'd like to do from here. You are setting your navbar to be 100vh, which is 100% height of the screen, so you need to make sure your padding and margin on your nav elements aren't so much. Try removing any margin and padding from these two styles, then adapt it on your own from here. If you don't want to change this stuff, refer to the second part of my answer, and just make the nav scrollable.

```
.navbar li a {
   margin-top: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 875px) {
.navbar.responsive li.navbar_items {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
}
```

Also, if you look in .navbar styling (line 8 of your codepen) you have it set to overflow: hidden. You can update your .navbar.responsive class with overflow of scroll to get it to work.

```
@media screen and (max-width:875px) {
.navbar.responsive {
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(236,201,205, 1);
  transition: background-color .6s;
  overflow: scroll; // Set overflow to scroll
}
}
```

Comment: No prob. Good luck with your epic css adventure.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happenes because you make `.navbar.responsive {
    position:fixed;`
And you just can't watch all content of block, because it's not allow to scroll. When i change this property to absolute, i looked all items of menu.

By the way, you write  CSS property font-weight with px, `font-weight: 700px`, but it shouldn't be px, it's relative value: `font-weight: 700`